# Wurtz reaction with two different alkyl halide

Tags: reaction-mechanism

$$\ce{C5H11Cl + C4H9I + 2Na ->}$$
Is this possible in a Wurtz reaction? I want to add 2 different alkyl halides with two different halogens. I'm curious if two different types of halogen on the alkyl reactants is possible.

Comment: This is going to be pretty messy. Each reagent will react not only with the other one, but also with itself.

Comment: As a side note, I would also mention the Corey-House synthesis, a method to couple asymmetrical halides. We transform one of the alkyl halides into a lithium dialkyl cuprate (R2CuLi) and react it with the other alkyl halide (R'X). The result would be a alkane R-R'.

Comment: There are going to be issues concerning separation as the products will have nearly same boiling points making fractional distillation difficult.

Answer (score 1):

The alkyl groups mentioned could be primary, secondary or tertiary
The last one's will not be going by Wurtz reaction (these will rather undergo elimination to give alkenes); only primary & secondary can.
Even here, we can have a mixture of products:[image]